# Durandal: Create function in one child and Consume from another child

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, durandal-2.0

I have a `Knockout` application developed using `Durandal.JS`. Here is the structure of my project:

```
- Parent
    - Index.js
    - Index.html
- Child1
    - Index.js
    - Index.html
- Child2
    - Index.js
    - Index.html
```

I have a function `UpdateData()` declared in `Child2/Index.js` and I want to consume that function from `Child1/Index.js`

Reason of declaring this function in `Child2` is, I have other variables and controls declared in Child2. And by calling `UpdateData()` method, I want to update the value of all variables declared in Child2.

I don't know how to handle this situation.

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in messaging events? http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe.html

Answer (score 0):

Durandal by default uses require to load modules. You could try to require the child2 module in your child1 module.

```
//child1 module
define(function (require) {

//require child2 into the module
var child2 = require('Child2/Index');

//use the method
child2.UpdateData();
});
```

For this to work, you must return the `UpdateData()` method from `Child2`.

```
//child2 module
define(function(){
return {
UpdateData:function(){
  //your method
}
}});
```

For more information, you could go through the docs on how to create a module that can be reused by other modules.
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module.html